# Smooth SVG animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am trying to refresh the animation with the given parameter rotateX and rotateY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var svg = document.getElementById("DC");
        var x = 10;
        var y = 0;
        for (j = 0; j<8 ; j++) {
            svg.setAttribute('style', 'transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;');
            x = x  + 10;
        }
    });
```

But it didn't work. How to refresh the animation smoothly ?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body><svg id="DC" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 500 408" class="sim" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;"><style></body>
```

Comment: Why don't you try using GreenSock for this: https://greensock.com/ Also I'm not sure is a very good idea to animate the SVG tag, better use groups or other display elements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each time you step the animation, you need to give the browser a chance to draw the changes.  You are not doing that.  Your `for` loop is just continuously changing the `style` attribute, and never returning control to the browser. It never has a chance to update the page.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.  Once upon a time it was common to use the `window.setTimeout()` call to return to the browser and get it to call your code in order to updat the animation.  Nowadays the preferred way is the [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) call.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("DC");
var x = 10;
var y = 0;

function step(timestamp)
{
   svg.setAttribute('style', 'transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;');
   x = x  + 10;
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="DC" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 500 408" class="sim" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;"></svg>
</body>
```

Here each step of the animation is calculated in the `step()` function. Then before you return from the function, you have to call `requestAnimation()` again to ask it to call `step()` again.

The call at the end is to start off the animation at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is to use CSS transitions.
This will allow you to define easily the speed and even the timing function used.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("DC");

function update(x)
{
   svg.setAttribute('style', 'transform: perspective(30em) rotateX('+x+'deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;');
}
svg.parentNode.offsetWidth;
update(80);

num.onchange = e => update(num.value);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<label>x rotation<input type="number" value="80" id="num"></label>
<svg id="DC" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 500 408" class="sim" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;"></svg>
```

And if you need it to loop, you can listen to the `transitionend` event :

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("DC");
x = 0;
function loop()
{
  x += 180;
  svg.setAttribute('style', 'transform: perspective(30em) rotateX('+x+'deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;');
}
svg.addEventListener('transitionend', loop);
svg.parentNode.offsetWidth;
loop();
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<svg id="DC" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 500 408" class="sim" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions to try:
     1. isolate element being transformed in the DOM by using absolute positioning and static dimensions
     2. Set css property [will-change: transform;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

```
<body>
       <div class="viewport" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 408px;">
             <svg id="DC" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 500 408" class="sim" width="500px" height="408px" style="transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; will-change: transform;">
               </svg>
         </div>
```

3. Use a transition timing function, such as [jquery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) rather than your for loop, which is instructing the browser to render all frames immediately. I'm not sure jquery can animate complex transforms, but [D3](https://d3js.org/) definite can. You can also do this to put your animation into an animation queue, though using a library with a timing function is still preferable:

```
function animate(frames,x) {
    if(frames > 0) {
        svg.setAttribute('style', 'transform: perspective(30em) rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg) scale(0.6, 0.6); perspective: 30em;');

         requestAnimationFrame(function() { animate(--frames,x+= 10); });
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I want to set the value X and increase by 10 every time I move my mouse, how do I do that? the animation is not working using that function.

Comment: You should listen for the mousemove event then, and put your animation code in there. Once you get a mousemove event, requestAnimationFrame(function() { animate(...) ; }); All of this is a lot easier using a framework - I like [D3](https://d3js.org/), which has tons of easily copied examples.